# how to use MDPI and HDPI?

Tags: android

I am devloping an application which requires deployment on various android devices. But how to select images based on different devices resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just put images in the folders .the android runtime decides from where to take images.
refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html